# Gerrit Trigger doesn't work when a build is running for that gerrit

Tags: jenkins, gerrit-trigger

This is a weird one.
On Jenkins, with Gerrit Trigger, I can trigger my jenkins job just fine using any of the configured triggers.

However, while that job is running - I can not trigger the same job again from the same gerrit so long as the previous build is still running.

I can trigger the same job from other gerrits, or trigger other jobs from that gerrit, but not the same job and the same gerrit.

Funny thing is - it's not even queued. The trigger is just completely ignored, it doesn't even start when the running job is finished.

Thins I've checked are that `Do not allow concurrent builds` is not checked (it indeed isn't) and that the label has enough executors available (it does).

Any idea what I could be missing?

Thanks!

Comment: There seems to be an open issue against the gerrit plugin which sounds like your problem

https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-63000